# Plotting based on occurrence in group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would to make a bar chart that plots the bar as a *proportion* of the total group rather than the usual *percentage*. For a `var` to "count" it only needs to occur once in a group. For example in this `df` where `id` is the grouping variable

```
df <-
tibble(id = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 3)),
       vars = c("a", NA, "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "a", "a"))
```

The a bars would be:

```
a = 2/3       # since a occurs in 2 out of 3 groups
b = 1/3    
c = 1/3   
d = 1/3   
e = 1/3
```

Comment: Please clarify the expected output.

Comment: Do you mean the proportion of groups (`id`) that each var occurs in?

Comment: yes, thank you @Axeman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, a one-liner would suffice:

```
ggplot(distinct(df)) + geom_bar(aes(vars, stat(count) / n_distinct(df$id)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Working answer:

```
tibble(id = c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 3)),
       vars = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "a", "a")) %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  distinct(vars) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  add_count(vars) %>% 
  mutate(prop = n / n_distinct(id)) %>% 
  distinct(vars, .keep_all = T) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(vars, prop)) +
  geom_col()
```